# Export just the first page, not all data

Tags: export, shieldui

Why does export table export just the first page, not all data in the table?

```
$("#button1").shieldButton({
        events: {
            click: function (e) {
                $('#grid').tableExport({ type: 'excel', escape: 'false', tableName: "shieldui-grid" });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The exporter will export only the currently loaded data. 
One possible option would be to disable paging, export and get all the data. At present, the exporting functionality will export the rendered element(s) in the page.